# Should I escape an expected integer value using mysql_real_escape_string or can I just use (int)$expectedinteger

Tags: php, mysql, casting, escaping, sql-injection

is it safe to use cast (int) instead of escaping?

```
class opinion
{
   function loadbyopinionid($opinionid){
      $opinionid=(int)$opinionid;
      mysql_query("select * from fe_opinion where opinionid=$opinionid");
      //more code 
   }
}
```

Comment: Since you are seemingly not using it as string within SQL context, escaping it with `_escape_string` would not be useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

mysql_real_scape_string is for **STRINGS**. it will not make an integer 'safe' for use. e.g.

```
$safe = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
```

will do NOTHING where

```
$_GET['page'] = "0 = 0";
```

because there's no SQL metacharacters in there. your query would end up something like

```
SELECT ... WHERE somefield = 0 = 0
```

However, doing intval() will convert that `0=0` into a plain `0`.

Comment: Exactly. `(int) $value` is safe, but one has to keep in mind, that there are side effects like `(int) "5abc" === 5`. So one should validate, that the given string is *just* a number, for example using `ctype_digit()`.

Comment: Wouldn't agree... because someone may pass string where integer was expected... it is much more safe to use it with all params.

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is safe, but you should escape the value in the query
..where opinionid='$opinionid'"

BTW 
(1) Never use Select *
Solution Select Field, Field2 ....

(2) (int)$foo is less perfomanter then intval($foo)

Comment: As I remember, intval() is slower than (int) (micro-improvement which is usually not worth the effort, as it the difference is invisible to the eye).